# Change formatting behavior for a URL in nbconvert

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jinja2, pandoc, nbconvert

I want to convert a Jupyter notebook to LaTeX using `nbconvert`. The default exporting behavior is to convert Jupyter hypertext links

```
[a link](http://some.website.com)
```

to a LaTeX string that can be rendered as a link in a PDF document:

```
\href{http://some.website.com}{a link}
```

I would like to change this behavior, so that links are rendered instead as footnotes:

```
a link\footnote{http://some.website.com}
```

What do I have to modify to do this? I've looked at the documentation for nbconvert but haven't been able to figure it out. Is it possible to do this within a `.tplx` template file? I've looked at the standard template files and don't see anything defining the URL behavior, so I'm guessing it's handled by `pandoc` somehow, but I'm confused about where I need to change something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use LaTeX to redefine the `\href` command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12774/changing-hrefs-to-footnotes). Put the following in your [template](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates) or using header-includes:

```
\let\oldhref=\href
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\footnote{\oldhref{#1}{#2}}}
```

Alternatively, you could write a [pandoc filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) to rewrite the actual output to a `RawInline "latex" "\footnote"`...